# Using Mod-Rewrite to change Paths into files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched both Google, and stackoverflow for more than 48 hrs, and I haven't found a similar question/solution; hence, my asking for help.

If I want to rewrite URLs such as `http://localhost/filename` to obtain filename.php (such that `localhost/aboutus` fetches `aboutus.php`, `localhost/contact` fetches `contact.php`, etc).

How do I do that? I don't want to write a rule for each of the pages; I want the 'filename' to be a dynamic so that a single rule will work for all the pages in the specific folder.

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php
```

In a .htaccess file, and I keep receiving a 500 error.
Thanks. 

 
The whole file contains this: 
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteBase /  
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php

 
That's all the file contains

Comment: Post your whole .htaccess file, please. The rule should work.

Comment: I've modified the question to include the content of the file. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 500 error can have lots of reasons - is there a way to obtain more information about it?

Anyway, possibly your problem is the greedy approach of (.*) and your handling of the trailing slash that may be there or not.

Try

```
RewriteRule ^([_a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?$ $1.php
```

instead which will only match the characters inside the [] and not include a '/'.

You can check your RewriteRules here: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: Thanks very much; that did the trick. The greedy .* was the one messing things up for me.